# Is there anyway to pass argc, argv outside of my main.cpp file?

Tags: c++, argv, argc

I've never really used argc, argv[] for reading in files however the program requirements would like me to use them. My issue is I'm reading in the files in a header file and processing it there instead of main. Is there a way to use the argc, argv[] inputs outside of main.cpp?

The header file I would like to use it in, replacing the "input.txt", etc with the argv.

**Would like to use here instead of output.txt**

```
void expression::convertToPostFix()
{
  {

  ofstream fout("output.txt"); 
  stack<char> stack;
  stringstream postfix;

  while (!obj.empty()) {
    stack.push('(');
    fout << "InFix is:\t";
    while (1) {
        if ((obj.front() != ';') && (obj.front() != '.'))
        {
            const char current = obj.front();         
            cout << current;
            fout << current;

            obj.pop();
            if (isspace(current)) {

            }
            else if (isalnum(current)) {
                postfix << current;
            }

            else if ('(' == current) {
                stack.push(current);
            }

            else if (isOperator(current)) {
                 char rightOperator = current;
                while (!stack.empty() && isOperator(stack.top()) &&                               precedence(stack.top(), rightOperator)) {
                    postfix << ' ' << stack.top();
                    stack.pop();
                }
                postfix << ' ';
                stack.push(rightOperator);
            }

            else if (')' == current) {

                while (!stack.empty() && '(' != stack.top()) {
                    postfix << ' ' << stack.top();
                    stack.pop();
                }

                stack.pop();
                postfix << ' ';
            }

        }
        else
        {
            obj.pop();
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!stack.empty() && '(' != stack.top()) {
        postfix << ' ' << stack.top();
        stack.pop();
    }

    stack.pop();
    pfix = postfix.str();
    postfix.str("");
  cout << "\nPost fix is:\t" << pfix << endl << endl;
  fout << "\nPost fix is:\t" << pfix << endl << endl;
    }

}
```

}

**(Would like it used here as well)**

```
   expression::expression()
{  

ifix = "";
pfix = "";
last = 0;

char chr;
ifstream fin;
fin.open("input.txt");


 while (!fin.eof())
 {
  fin >> chr;

  if (!fin.eof())
  {
      if (chr != ' ')
      {
          obj.push(chr);
      }
   }


  }

}
```

Comment: Just pass e.g. `argv[1]` to the function that needs the first argument? After checking that `argc >= 2` of course.

Comment: BTW, a common coding guideline is to place code in source files and declarations in header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question, **YES** it is possible to pass `argc` and `argv` outside of the main function.

Very simple usage program, where it uses the command line argument. It passes argv[0] as an argument to the show_usage method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

static void show_usage(std::string name)
{
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <option(s)> SOURCES"
              << "Options:\n"
              << "\t-h,--help\t\tShow this help message\n"
              << "\t-d,--destination DESTINATION\tSpecify the destination path"
              << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        show_usage(argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector <std::string> sources;
    std::string destination;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::string arg = argv[i];
        if ((arg == "-h") || (arg == "--help")) {
            show_usage(argv[0]);
            return 0;
        } else if ((arg == "-d") || (arg == "--destination")) {
            if (i + 1 < argc) { // Make sure we aren't at the end of argv!
                destination = argv[i++]; // Increment 'i' so we don't get the argument as the next argv[i].
            } else { // Uh-oh, there was no argument to the destination option.
                  std::cerr << "--destination option requires one argument." << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }  
        } else {
            sources.push_back(argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return move(sources, destination);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend your function and pass `argv` and `argc` to it:

```
expression::expression(int argc, char ** argv)
```

Call:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    ...
    expression::expression(argc, argv);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing your `main` function should do is turn those character arrays into a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> const args(argv, argv + argc);
```

You can then pass that `std::vector<std::string>` to whereever it's needed:

```
void expression::expression(std::vector<std::string> const &args)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> const args(argv, argv + argc);
    expression::expression(args);
}
```

If that's not a viable solution because the vector would have to pass through a lot of intermediate layers, you may find the following approach better. Create the following function somewhere:

```
std::vector<std::string>& CommandLineArgs()
{
    static std::vector<std::string> args;
    return args;
}
```

In `main`, set the value:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> const args(argv, argv + argc);
    CommandLineArgs() = args;
}
```

Everywhere else in your program, read from it:

```
void expression::expression()
{
    auto const& args = CommandLineArgs();
    // ...
}
```

---

Working with a `std::vector<std::string>` is much easier than handling a pointer with a separate array-size value.